# Facebook IE8/9 & Firefox - how to break out of iFrame from link

Tags: facebook

I have a link in my Facebook page tab app which should send the client to the app Canvas page, works fine in Chrome but just isn't going in IE or Firefox.  It's a really simple link

```
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/mycanvasapp" target="_top">link</a>
```

but it just reloads the tab page when done in IE or Firefox.  Is there a trick with IE or Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higly likely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103986/facebook-apps-redirect-to-hosting-url-in-the-first-usage/8104023#8104023) case:

When you redirect user to your canvas page: As it will be asked for authorization(while you do this test  none Chrome), once he gives authorization, he will fall to: http://yourapp.com

Then while you repeat same action for same "already authorized user", he will fall into your canvas url: https://apps.facebook.com/yourapp

Comment: I think that may have been it, or something similar.  Thanks